# Sublime Text 3: how do you configure the display and/or sorting of the Window menu?

Tags: sublimetext3

If you open a couple folders in Sublime Text 3, you'll see entries for each folder added to the Window menu. It appears that the default format of each entry on the menu is:

(active-filename) - (foldername)

The list on the Window menu is sorted alphabetically starting with (active-filename). Whenever you select a file to work on, the (active-filename) part of the entry changes, and the list reorders itself. If you have a dozen Windows open, the position of a given window in the list will change all the time as you work with files. This makes it hard to find a window when repeatedly switching between Windows.

Is there a way to configure Sublime Text 3 to display only the folder name in the list on the Windows menu? Alternatively, is there a way to configure it to sort on folder name and not on the ever-changing "active" filename?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there open issues around this but no attention form the SublimeText Team yet

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/alphabetize-window-menu-by-folder-not-file-name/13017/4

https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1972

https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1445

https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1179